# Combining elements in select dropdown while maintaining correct id in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

So I have a dropdown where I want it to look like this so that they can see the fullname.  However when this is done it always puts student_id as 0 in my join table.

```
= f.association :student, as: :select, label: false, input_html: {class: "form-control" },
prompt: "Select a Student", collection: Student.all.map{|s| "#{s.firstname} #{s.lastname}"}
```

To get it to work I have to remove the `collection: ...`

Is there another way to get it, such as setting value to id?

Comment: If you inspect the select options what are their values set as? I'm guessing you need to specify a way for the association to know what values to set for each student name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  All I had to do is add a array inside the collection block with the first item displayed and the second item as the id.  So it should look like this:

```
collection: Student.all.map{|s| ["#{s.firstname} #{s.lastname}",s.id] }
```